# OpenMP tasks execution time varies depending on where I put the pragmas

Tags: c, openmp, timing

I'm trying to parallelize some code using OpenMP (and MPI) using tasks. I have the following code:

```
double t_copy = 0, t_forward = 0, t_backward = 0, t_diag = 0;
void pc_ssor_poisson3d(int N, void *data,
                       double *restrict Ax,
                       double *restrict x)
{
// clocks for timing
#define COPY_CLOCK 20
#define FW_SSOR_CLOCK 21
#define DIAG_SSOR_CLOCK 22
#define BW_SSOR_CLOCK 23

    pc_ssor_p3d_t *ssor_data = (pc_ssor_p3d_t *)data;
    int n = ssor_data->n;
    double w = ssor_data->omega;
    tic(COPY_CLOCK);
#ifdef PAR_PC
    parallel_copy(N, Ax, x);
#else
    memcpy(Ax, x, N * sizeof(double));
#endif
    t_copy += toc(COPY_CLOCK);
    tic(FW_SSOR_CLOCK);
#ifdef PAR_PC

        parallel_ssor_forward_sweep(n, 0, n, 0, n, 0, n, Ax, w); // --1--

#else
...
```

This is the function `parallel_ssor_forward_sweep`:

```
void parallel_ssor_forward_sweep(int n, int i1, int i2, int j1, int j2, int k1, int k2, double *restrict Ax, double w)
{
    char *dep_matrix = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (i2 - i1) / BS * (j2 - j1) / BS * (k2 - k1) / BS);
    // --2--
    for (int k = 0; k < (k2 - k1) / BS; k++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (j2 - j1) / BS; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < (i2 - i1) / BS; i++)
            {
                // ssor_forward_sweep_pwrap(n, i1 + i * BS, i1 + (i + 1) * BS, j1 + j * BS, j1 + (j + 1) * BS, k1 + k * BS, k1 + (k + 1) * BS, Ax, w, dep_matrix, i, j, k);
                ssor_forward_sweep_pwrap(n, i1, i2, j1, j2, k1, k2, Ax, w, dep_matrix, i, j, k);
            }
        }
    }
    free(dep_matrix);
    
}
```

The function `ssor_forward_sweep_pwrap` actually creates the OpenMP task, I'll attach the code:

```
void ssor_forward_sweep_pwrap(int n, int i1, int i2, int j1, int j2, int k1, int k2, double *restrict Ax, double w, char *dep_matrix, int i, int j, int k)
{
#define dep_mat(i, j, k) (dep_matrix[(k * (j2 - j1) + j) * (i2 - i1) + i])

    char *top_dep = k - 1 >= 0 ? &dep_mat(i, j, k - 1) : NULL;
    char *left_dep = j - 1 >= 0 ? &dep_mat(i, j - 1, k) : NULL;
    char *back_dep = i - 1 >= 0 ? &dep_mat(i - 1, j, k) : NULL;
    char *out_dep = &dep_mat(i, j, k);

#pragma omp task depend(in                                          \
                        : *top_dep, *left_dep, *back_dep) depend(inout \
                                                              : *out_dep)

    {
        ssor_forward_sweep(n, i1 + i * BS, i1 + (i + 1) * BS, j1 + j * BS, j1 + (j + 1) * BS, k1 + k * BS, k1 + (k + 1) * BS, Ax, w);
    }
#undef dep_mat
}
```

Pragma directive:

```
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp single
    {
    }
```

Now the problem is that if I put the directive above to make the code parallel around the `parallel_ssor_forward_sweep` call (marked with the comment --1-- in the code) I get much better times (around 9.6/9.7 seconds for that code section) vs if I put it around the for marked in the code with --2-- comment, so getting the whole function code but the malloc (times 12.7/12.8 seconds).

I've executed the code 3 times for each to make sure it wasn't a fluke and with the same number of threads (6 in this case).

I'm running on my university machine which supposedly should not have any other program running at the same time as mine for the allocated resources.

The reason why I believe this behaviour is strange is that inside the pragma omp single region I expect one single thread to execute the code, so I don't think having the malloc inside or outside the region should lead to such a difference.

Also the code gives the same result and is run with the same input.

Comment: What pragma are you testing at the two marked locations?  You say "the directive above" but the only OMP directive I see anywhere in that code is a `#pragma omp task`, which will not, by itself, parallelize anything.

Comment: @JohnBollinger sorry when I edited the code I accidentally deleted the code I was referring to, I fixed it now

Comment: Yes I'll try and get the parts of the code that are needed

Comment: It appears to me that when you put the directives at `--1--`, your program has undefined behavior.  This arises because the lifetime of the mallocated object used by the tasks is not ensured to encompass the full execution of the tasks.  (Execution of the tasks is not ensured complete until the close of the parallel region to which they are bound.)  Putting the directives at `--2--` resolves this issue.

Comment: Have you verified that the tasks are in fact distributed across multiple threads in both cases?  It is conceivable that your OpenMP implementation recognizes the object lifetime issue, and rescues it when it applies by executing all the generated tasks in the same one thread that encounters the `task` construct (which it is permitted to do in any case).  What happens if you disable OpenMP or remove the OMP directives?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think I understand what you're saying in the first comment, that the thread that executes the code that spawns the task could get to the free before the tasks are finished, so I think adding a `pragma omp taskwait` before the `free` would fix the undefined behaviour right? I tested the code with the taskwait and indeed I get similar times to the directives at --2--, so I think you are spot on! Thank you!

Comment: Still if you have any suggestion on why the parallel code (i.e. without the `#pragma omp task`) is faster than the parallel one I would appreciate it a lot

Comment: Yes, you have correctly understood the issue I raised.  My guess about why the flawed version is faster is the subject of my most recent comment preceding this one.  I speculate that in that case, the tasks are all being executed by the same thread (which OMP allows), and that this is faster than executing them in parallel on account of all the data dependencies.  Emphasis on *speculate*.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I tested your hypothesis by having a counter for the various threads id in one parallel section and it looks like you're right in your speculation, as I see all the counters at 0 but for one thread that has a value different than 0, I guess I'm going to have to check my dependencies because I was expecting the parallel code to be much faster than the sequential one. Thank you again!

Comment: I have no clue what `ssor_forward_sweep()` does, so I can only assume that the dependencies expressed in the code are correct.  In that case, you should be able to bring the parallel version performance closer to the serial performance by coarsening the granularity of your computation.  That might mean increasing `BS` or pushing the `i` loop into the task.  Or both.  It is conceivable that such measures would bring parallel performance meaningfully past serial performance.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't know if it is relevant to the question but I'll share why I didn't get the speedup by running the parallel code: (1) I was missing the `*` in the depend clause (I fixed it now in the question) (2) the macro I defined to get the elements of the dependency matrix sometimes didn't give the right result (haven't figured out why). When I substituted the macro with the same formula for calculating the index the tasks were scheduled in the right way

Comment: It is **undefined behavior** to dereference a null pointer.

Comment: You should use `(k)` in the macro to get the correct result: `#define dep_mat(i, j, k) (dep_matrix[((k) * (j2 - j1) + (j)) * (i2 - i1) + (i)])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, as mentioned by @JohnBollinger in the comments, was due to the fact that when I put the `pragma` as below, the thread that executed the `#pragma omp single` region could get to the `free(dep_matrix)` before the other threads had ended.

```
#ifdef PAR_PC
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp single
    {
        parallel_ssor_forward_sweep(n, 0, n, 0, n, 0, n, Ax, w);
    }
#else
```

By putting `pragma` inside the `parallel_ssor_forward_sweep` function like below, the thread executing the `#pragma omp single` region has to wait for the other threads at the end of the region (i.e. before the `free(dep_matrix)`), and so the matrix is still available when the other threads need it.

```
void parallel_ssor_forward_sweep(int n, int i1, int i2, int j1, int j2, int k1, int k2, double *restrict Ax, double w)
{
    char *dep_matrix = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (i2 - i1) / BS * (j2 - j1) / BS * (k2 - k1) / BS);
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp single
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < (k2 - k1) / BS; k++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < (j2 - j1) / BS; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < (i2 - i1) / BS; i++)
                {
                    // ssor_forward_sweep_pwrap(n, i1 + i * BS, i1 + (i + 1) * BS, j1 + j * BS, j1 + (j + 1) * BS, k1 + k * BS, k1 + (k + 1) * BS, Ax, w, dep_matrix, i, j, k);
                    ssor_forward_sweep_pwrap(n, i1, i2, j1, j2, k1, k2, Ax, w, dep_matrix, i, j, k);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    free(dep_matrix);
}
```